# How can I put image to actiobar list?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to put image to action bar list like Path app does:

[image]

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Spinner` in the action bar is no different than any other `Spinner` that exists in your layouts. The adapter that you give it, an instance of `SpinnerAdapter`, has two callbacks methods: one for the layout used in the drop-down list and one which is used for the selected item layout.

Knowing this, it's likely they use the same layout for the selected item layout which simply shows their logo whereas they retain the normal drop-down layout for displaying the navigation items.

Answer (score 0):

There are three images in that action bar. The two right ones are standard action items (`<item>` in menu resource with `android:showAsAction` set to something like `ifRoom`). The left one is probably a logo (`android:logo` in manifest), turn on via `setDisplayUseLogoEnabled()` on `ActionBar`.